# Progressive jpg image transforms?

Tags: image-transforms

I want to use progressive jpg files and want to know if craft image transforms save jpg images as progressive, or can they be made to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve progressive JPGs if your server has [Imagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installed, but it doesn't look like the [image processing library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) that Craft is using has added support for it, yet.

Comment: Does this mean that one day Craft will support transforming progressive JPGs? Provided Imagick is installed of course.

Comment: It'd be a lot more likely if Imagine adds support for it.

Comment: Right-o. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At least in the current version (3.2.6+)

On the image transformation page, you can select one of the interlacing methods under the "Interlacing" heading. I'm not exactly sure the differences or pros/cons of each but I've used "Partition" and it works well.

[image: Screenshot showing "Partition" under Interlacing]

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. Images are still nog progressive.